How to fix "/home/victor/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/build/classes/groovy/main/"
I'am use linux mint,I was try install flutter sdk from snap but when run app will get this error.

startup failed:
/home/victor/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/build/classes/groovy/main/FlutterPlugin$_addTasksForOutputsAppLinkSettings_closure13$_closure41$_closure43$_closure44$_closure45$_closure47$_closure54$_closure59$_closure60.class (File name too long)

1 error


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --info option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Visit Flutter's official website and download the latest stable release for Linux.

um install the last stable version

It is obvious File name too long, it prints this error   /// https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138748
